# jQuery does not load inside page.evaluate

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs

I am writing a phantomjs automation script that involves jQuery.

I'll try to be brief.

**First - the page load**

Version 1:

```
page.includeJs("http://............../1.9.0/jquery.min.js", function() {
  page.open(urlDecoded, function (status) {
    page.evaluate(fChecker, params);
  });
});
```

Version 2

```
page.open(urlDecoded, function (status) {
  page.includeJs("http://............../1.9.0/jquery.min.js", function() {
    page.evaluate(fChecker, params);
  });
});
```

Version 3

```
page.open(urlDecoded, function (status) {
  page.evaluate(fChecker, params);
});
```

**Second - the evaluation**

For version 1 and 2:

```
function fChecker(params) {
  ...
  ...
  $('.blabla').val('yes');
}
```

For version 3:

```
function fChecker(params) {
  var jq = document.createElement('script');
  jq.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js";
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
  ...
  ...
  $('.blabla').val('yes');
}
```

**Last - the result**

$ is not recognized.
jQuery is not recognized.

I save HTML content after the evaluation and in shows my script inside the automated page - so it does add the file correctly.

The very same approach (Version 2) works already with two other sites and everything is fine.

Using another evaluation function later (just for submitting the page a evaluated and analyzed) works fine.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

PS. I've searched every single item on the site. The topic is not duplication.

Comment: you're mixing valid and invalid code, that's a bit unclear. What's the problem ?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear.
The point is - I tried to use jQuery inside target pages but kept receiving "$ is not recognized." and "jQuery is not recognized."

The answer is - jQuery is loaded already by the target page and the second instance (I load) interfere with each other.

Solutions:
1. Don't load jQuerty twice and use the loaded one.
2. Use jQuery.noConflict() and define another alias for the instance you load

Another question I was trying to ask here - what is the best place to load external JS files? Inside page.open() or outside it?

My choice is - inside it.

Thanks